# Views3 Integration instructions not working

Tags: extension, drupal-views

I followed these [instructions](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Views3+Integration) to integrate Views3 with a custom CiviCRM extension.

I have Drupal 7 and I copied and pasted the array just under the $databases one in "settings.php" .
I clear the Views's cache and then go to the "Add new view" panel.

The Show select lists only few CiviCRM tables (I saw them also before the integration procedure) but not all and not the ones of the custom CiviCRM extension.

I have two separate databases for Drupal and CiviCRM but the drupal user has access rights to the CiviCRM tables.

Does someone can help with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/exposing-tables-views-drupal-7/) on how to expose Tables to Views in Drupal 7.

Now I'm writing a module that expose the tables of the CiviCRM extension that
I have to use and it seems to work as far as I tried.

Answer (score 0):

As an indirect solution to your problem: Instead of using the instructions you saw for Views integration, you might also consider using the Drupal modules "CiviCRM Entity" or "Views CiviCRM Expose Tables".  This way is not only D8-compatible, but should save you the headache of editing settings.php.

Comment: The  [Views CiviCRM Expose Tables module](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/markusa/2474103) says to follow that instructions too. However I installed both, but can't see any new admin panel...  What should I do or where should I check once installed the two modules in order to use the CiviCRM tables for the view? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.
With either Views CiviCRM Expose Tables or CiviCRM Entity, I don't think you'll see a new admin panel.  You'll just go to edit a View and when you go to add fields, you'll have more options.